# Android Development: Using Image From Assets In A WebView's HTML

Tags: android, image, webview, local

In my app I'm making a basic HTML help document.
I wanted my app's logo in the HTML img tag itself, but I don't know how I'd reference to the logo which will be stored in assets.

Is this possible, if so how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can try http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=369
and
http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/33/

Comment: @alexPriceXp i have the same problem as you... will you help me.. to put images in the webview html.???

Comment: @siten Well in the end I scrapped using HTML and instead decided to use Android's widgets to make the help document for my app as I still couldn't find a way to refer to an image in my app's assets folder in HTML.

Comment: for latest versions you can follow below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009716/3886504

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Put your Logo into the assets directory eg: assets/logo.png

Then load your html with:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Reference your img like:

```
<img src="logo.png">
```

Comment: it seems like `loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/, html, ..."` is the key to get it to show an image. Using `WebView.loadData(strHTML, "text/html", "utf-8");` doesn't show an image that's residing in assets.

Comment: Make sure you have ending "/" at the base url path.

Answer (score 24):

Store the images in assets folder:

[image]

Read the image in the html from assets with `file:///android_asset/`

for example:

```
String sHtmlTemplate = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\"file:///android_asset/img/mybadge.png\"></body></html>";
```

load inside the WebView:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sHtmlTemplate, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Comment: The image doesn't show up when using <img src="file:///android_asset/img/mybadge.png">. I had to use @spatialist solution which involves the use of webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Comment: ok i have edited my answer, the way that load the data inside the webview is different.

Comment: @Elenasys I am trying to do something similar but I get this error :-chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///sdcard/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png" I have also posted a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019828/how-to-open-a-image-stored-locally-using-html-code-in-android

Answer (score 6):

You can reference assets with this URL syntax:

```
file:///android_asset/YourAssetFilename
```

Comment: I know it works because I use it in one of my apps.  The syntax definitely works in code, such as: 

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/blah.png")

And this site indicates it should also work in HTML, see the section about "Creating HTML that references resources bundled in the APK file itself".   http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=369

Comment: This does not work for me when including resources from inside the web view. I am not trying to load a file in code but from html.

Answer (score 6):

dump them into assets folder and just put in the html

```
<img src="filename.png">
```

simple as that

Comment: this is work !!! of cource you should put your html in assets folder,too.

Answer (score 2):

Put your Logo into the assets directory 
   Example : assets/logo.png

Then

```
String imgData="<img src=home.png>";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", imgData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider we have placed an image `your_image.png` in `assets/imgs`.

In earlier versions of android you can directly access images like below.

```
webView.loadData("<img src='file:///android_asset/imgs/your_image.png'/>",
        "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

But can't access files directly in latest versions due to added security concerns. for the latest versions we need to use `WebViewAssetLoader`. refer the below code.

> Helper class to load local files including application's static assets and resources using http(s):// URLs inside a WebView class. Loading local files using web-like URLs instead of "file://" is desirable as it is compatible with the Same-Origin policy.

```
    final WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
            .addPathHandler("/assets/", new WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this))
            .build();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                                          WebResourceRequest request) {
            return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
        }
    });
    webView.loadData("<img src='https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/imgs/your_image.png'/>",
            "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

for more information please refer android dev portal links
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/webkit?fireglass_rsn=true