# How to get the image from drawable folder in android?

Tags: android

I am working on quiz application. I stored the column data in the following form in sqlite database.
[image]

I am able to retrieve the question but now I need to retrieve the image of that particular question. I kept the images in drawable folder. But I need to change the `i.e src="/test/image1.png" to src="/drawable/image1.png"`. If I change the path like the path of the 
image in sqlite colum at then can I get the image which I kept in my drawable folder? Please help me regarding this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779789/android-development-using-image-from-assets-in-a-webviews-html

Comment: You can find that out yourself by trying it.

Answer (score 7):

I would insist that in database you can just give the name of the image and then you can get the image using [`getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29),

```
getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", getPackageName());
```

Where name will be the name of your image i.e - `"image1"`

Answer (score 6):

It can be done like this aswell:

```
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
```

where this refers to the context of the actual activity.

Answer (score 2):

getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", getPackageName());

Answer (score 0):

just name the src="image1.png"
and put the files in your assets folder images and html