# Is it possible to access R.drawable variables dynamically?

Tags: java, android, resources

Let's say I want to access to my image : R.drawable.character

I have
`String drawableName = character`

Is there a way to do something like that or it is forbidden in Java =>

`R.drawable.drawableName` to access R.drawable.character ?

*I found this but it is for sql database : [How to get the image from drawable folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683501/how-to-get-the-image-from-drawable-folder-in-android)*

Comment: See [this question about how to get drawable resources…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22/29041466)

Comment: Didn't found what I was lookin' for in it.

Comment: `ImageView yourImgView = new ImageView();`  `yourImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.character, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand in what it does what I was looking for. Is myimage a variable like in my example ? I'm not looking to display a resource but to call it by its name contained in a variable.

Comment: You want to access the drawable, but what are you planning to do? The above comment shows how to add the resource to a GUI element that displays an image… If that is not what you want, then please explain it more clearly ;-)

Comment: I think my example is pretty clear => Having `R.drawable.character` and doing something like : `String drawableName = character; R.drawable.drawableName;` to access dynamically  `R.drawable.character` ^^

Comment: OK, then I got it wrong, sry... I see you got the right answer, good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks ! And thanks for taking your time for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName , type, package);
```

This will get you the ID of the resource you are looking for. With it, you can then access the resource from the R class.

Comment: Thanks, this is totally what I was looking for ! I'm just clueless about type and package, I don't know what to put there. Could you tell me ^^ ?

Comment: getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It really helps me a looooot !