# File not found when I try to load html into webview

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to load the html file with this line. (I get file name from intent)

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/content/" + file + ".html");
```

The html file is at:

```
/raw/res/content/1-introduction.html
```

I get this error:

```
The webpage at "file:///android_res/raw/content/1-introduction.html" couldn't be loaded because net:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20260530/150978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my files into /assets/content folder and called like this. Worked.

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/content/" + file + ".html");
```

Answer (score 0):

To load files packed in your application, you should use special WebViewAssetLoader. [There is a full guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/load-local-content). In general, you have to use special path handlers to operate local files.