# Unable to load images that are placed into the html files

Tags: android

I have one html file which consists of images in it. When I try to load that html file using webview, the html file loads but images didn't.

Main Activity File Code(activity_about)

```
 webviewAbout=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_about);

 webviewAbout.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html");
```

activity_about.xml code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="NestedWeights,UselessParent" >
  <!-- main layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:orientation="horizontal">  <!-- First layout -->

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibtn_about_back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"

                android:src="@drawable/backiconlogo" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/paniclogo" />

        </LinearLayout>                                     

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:background="@color/TechWhite">
                    <WebView 
                        android:id="@+id/webview_about"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout                                   
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:background="@color/TechWhite">
        <Button
               android:id="@+id/btn_exit_about" 
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="0.5"
               android:text="Exit"
               android:padding="10dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:background="@color/Blackish_Yellow"
               android:textColor="@color/Brownnish"/>

        </LinearLayout>                         
</LinearLayout>
```

about.html file

```
<html>
    <head>      <h2 align="center">About</h2>
            <h2 align="center">Panic App</h2>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#f8f8ec">
        <h1 align="center"><img src="E:\PANIC APP\assets\images\Paniclogo.png"/></h1>
        <p align="center">Version 1.0</p>
        <p align="center"></br>The “Panic App” is a emergency kind Application that it will help you out to get out of any “Emergency” situation by sending you help at the place you are.</p>
        <p align="center">It will also guide you that what “Primary” measure you should take during such Panic situation.</p>       

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't see any webview in your layout file?

Comment: Their.... check it properly...

Comment: sorry, missed it completely :)

Comment: can you share about.html? maybe the src of images is not accessible.

Comment: This `E:\PANIC APP\assets\images\Paniclogo.png` is a path to your local file system. Android won't be able to load this file because it's not stored inside the device's storage. Check this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779789/android-development-using-image-from-assets-in-a-webviews-html

Comment: I have shared it...so kindly check it out... thanks in advance..

Comment: Hassan Ibraheem..... As I reffered this post a back... but I didn't find any of the solution.... it would be glad if u just me a better way....thanks in advancde

Comment: @HassanIbraheem As I reffered this post a back... but I didn't find any of the solution.... it would be glad if u just me a better way....thanks in advancde

Comment: Please tell us where is the image located wrt about.html

Comment: @AnkitPopli the image is located at assets/images folder....

Comment: then please try chaging the img src to `images/Paniclogo.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Many times it occurs just due to nomenclature.
ensure that name of image file and name of image used are the same( check for uppercase and lowercase characters also).