# I need to pass parameter in html to load in webView android

Tags: android, html, android-assets

I need to pass parameter in the attribute "src" from tag "image" and "embed" for to load in webView, but the parameter has to be from assets.

How can i to make this?

```
    int height = PKViewSize.getHeightOfDisplay(context);
    int width  = PKViewSize.getWidthOfDisplay(context);

    String html = "<html>"
                    + "<head>"
                        + "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\"> <title></title>"
                    + "</head>"
                    + "<body bgcolor=\"#000000\"> "
                        + "<img src=\"Galeria_Menu5-Img_2.png\">"
                        + "<center>"
                            + "<article> "
                                + "<param name=wmode value=transparent>"
                                + "<embed src=\"1.swf \" height=\" +" + height + "+ \"  width=\"+" + width + "+\" wmode=transparent "
                                + "type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" /> "
                            + "</article>"
                        + "</center>"
                    + "</body>"
                + "</html>";

    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: to pass parameters via assets directory.

Comment: I think this is the same question
[Android Development: Using Image From Assets In A WebView's HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779789/android-development-using-image-from-assets-in-a-webviews-html)