# How to insert drawables in text

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, imageview

I want to insert small pictures, like arrow icons for example, into certain positions of contents of a `TextView`.

The photo below depicts exactly what I want:

[image: this is how I want to embed icons in the text]

Obviously, the most naive solution is to use multiple `TextView` on either side of the small `ImageView` objects. But this approach is not scalable.

I am curious to learn if someone has overcome this problem with some simple yet smart trick.
(Maybe with help from HTML or an external library)

Any efficient solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this project: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

Comment: @Egor: That is great, but offers text placed only after the image, so in the case of above picture, I would have to utilize and align 5 IconTextView objects, plus 1 TextView.

Comment: At which point is this error happening? Can't believe it's appearing immediately and in order to help you properly, you should add your current layout as well.

Comment: I have included the layout, the problem happens only when I set more than two lines of text to my TextViewWithImage object.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can create SpannableString and add any object to your string

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(textView.getText());

int start = 3;
int end = 4;
int flag = 0;
spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, start, end, flag);

textView.setText(spannableString);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I have 5 images to put into text, not just one. Can your solution be scaled up to meet my stated needs?

Comment: Add a new ImageSpan to spannableString for each image you want to insert.

Answer (score 14):

There was a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text) a while back and someone came up with an awesome solution. I've just tweaked this one a little bit so that the image-size is always as tall as the line. So basically your icons will **scale with the textSize**.

### Step 1 - Create a new View

Create a new Java class which extends `TextView`

```
public class TextViewWithImages extends TextView {

    public TextViewWithImages(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }
    public TextViewWithImages(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public TextViewWithImages(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        Spannable s = getTextWithImages(getContext(), text, this.getLineHeight());
        super.setText(s, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }

    private static final Spannable.Factory spannableFactory = Spannable.Factory.getInstance();

    private static boolean addImages(Context context, Spannable spannable, float height) {
        Pattern refImg = Pattern.compile("\\Q[img src=\\E([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)\\Q/]\\E");
        boolean hasChanges = false;

        Matcher matcher = refImg.matcher(spannable);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            boolean set = true;
            for (ImageSpan span : spannable.getSpans(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), ImageSpan.class)) {
                if (spannable.getSpanStart(span) >= matcher.start()
                        && spannable.getSpanEnd(span) <= matcher.end()
                        ) {
                    spannable.removeSpan(span);
                } else {
                    set = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            String resName = spannable.subSequence(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1)).toString().trim();
            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            Drawable mDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)height, (int)height);
            if (set) {
                hasChanges = true;
                spannable.setSpan(  new ImageSpan(mDrawable),
                        matcher.start(),
                        matcher.end(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                );
            }
        }

        return hasChanges;
    }
    private static Spannable getTextWithImages(Context context, CharSequence text, float height) {
        Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
        addImages(context, spannable, height);
        return spannable;
    }
}
```

### Step 2 - Usage in layout

Now in your layout-xml just use the TextViewWithImages class

```
<com.stacko.examples.TextViewWithImages
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="@string/my_string_with_icons" />
```

### Step 3 - Creating strings with icons

As you can see in the `addImages(...)` function of the `TextViewWithImages` class, a special pattern (`[img src=my_icon/]`) within the string is used in order to add the images.
So here's a example:

```
<string name="my_string_with_icons">The [img src=ic_action_trash/] is used to delete an item while the [img src=ic_action_edit/] is to edit one.</string>
```

The output:

[image]

And as previously said it will scale with your `textSize`:

[image]

As initially said most of this post is taken from [18446744073709551615](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755804/18446744073709551615) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text). I think this should be published as a library since it's a common use-case to have images in the text. :<

Comment: any idea about the crash?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce the error. I've just set 20 lines to my `TextViewWithImages` and no crash occured. Which Android-Version does your device run on?

Comment: 4.2.2, I need to insert up to 5 drawables.

Comment: this seems to affect line spacing. is there a way to avoid that ? my image is at the very end of the text so i was hoping for a way to avoid disrupting line spacing.

Comment: @j2emanue Well the size is of the drawable is set to height of the line itself (before adding the image). It may be an option to reduce the size in the Drawable#setBounds method.

Comment: Nice solution :) If anyone like me encounters problems using _proguard_ and `shrinkResources` (where the resource will be discarded unless you have other usages) - take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html -> `Customize which resources to keep`

Comment: @Behnam: Recently got this exception. The problem was I mistakenly deleted the drawable specified in the string resource. Once I placed the drawable again, it solved the issue. This problem comes because, when you run code analysis, the Lint detects that drawable as unused since its not *technically* referred from anywhere. Need to think of some way to prevent such deletion henceforth.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) instead of a `TextView`. This also allows you to display images from your asset folder.

See [Android Development: Using Image From Assets In A WebView's HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779789/android-development-using-image-from-assets-in-a-webviews-html) for more details.

Comment: That's a good idea, though I rather use drawable folder instead of assets, because I need to use different images for different Locales and screens efficiently.
Anyway, I appreciate your solution.