# adding a image from cam to a dynamically made html string

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to add a image that i take from phones camera
and add it to a html that is build dynamically from user input.
so i cant get the html file from assets.

all the question/answers i found are for local images and html from assets.
[Android - local image in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127696/android-local-image-in-webview)
[Android Development: Using Image From Assets In A WebView's HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779789/android-development-using-image-from-assets-in-a-webviews-html)

any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers in the links you showed, suggests to use Base64 embedded image:

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/9000691/1271435)

```
  <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

  xxxxx = base64 encoded string of images bytes
```

This sounds like a good idea, and one way to do it is something like this:

After taking the image with camera you should get back an `imageUri` of the photo.
then:
1.Get the input stream of that image:
`InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);`

2.Fill in the stream into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fillStream(stream, baos); // dummy method, provide implementation
```

3.Convert the byte array to Base64:
`String base64Image = new String(Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT));`

Then you can use the base64 string as the data for your image in HTML.