# How to show multiple Image from Android assets?

Tags: java, android, html, image, assets

I want to show images from android assets folder.

I have developed an apps with sqlite database. The sqlite database entry outputs as HTML.

Most of the HTMl tags worked fine such as `<strong>,<b>,<h1>,<a href=""></a>` etc.

But my stored Images in assets folder does not show by `<img src="">` tag.

I try like these...

Database entry:

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/image/icon.png"> 
<img src=\"file:///android_asset/image/icon.png\"> 
<img src="file:///android_res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png"/> 
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS
```

---

Java code:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(strHtml));
```

---

Screenshot:

[image: Lorem Ipsum]

Comment: Please refer the below link [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779789/android-development-using-image-from-assets-in-a-webviews-html#answer-14405801)

Comment: Hi my code not webview, text outputs as Html format. 
`android.text.Html;`