# How to open a image stored locally using html code in android?

Tags: android, html, image, jsoup

I am using jsoup to parse html and webview to display html content. In the process I am changing the source for a image. So when in html this line is executed `<img src="sdcard/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png" alt="downloadr" width="191" height="129" />`
the image doesn't load i.e. the there is space left for the image but it does not contain the actual image. How can I achieve this in android?
This is the code I am using.

```
    private void showJson(String json) {
        ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
        pj.parseJSON();
        String[] instruction = ParseJSON.instruction;


        for (int i = 0; i < instruction.length; i++)
        {

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(instruction[i]);

            if (doc.select("img[src]").attr("src").contains("download-r.png"))
            {
                Elements image = doc.select("img[src]");
                String imgsource = image.attr("src");
                downloadImages(imgsource);
                Boolean isSDPresent = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
                if (isSDPresent)
                {
                    image.attr("src","sdcard/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png");
                }else
                {
                    image.attr("src","/storage/emulated/0/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png");
                }
            }
            Log.d("Clean", String.valueOf(doc));
//            String imgsrc = images.attr("src");

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadData(String.valueOf(doc),"text/html","UTF-8");


            Elements paragraphs = doc.select("ul li ");
            for (Element element: paragraphs)
            {
                Log.d("PARAGRAPHS",element.text());

            }



            //Log.d("SOURCE",imgsrc);
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imgsrc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

This is the html that I am trying to display in a webview.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>The Comprehensive R Archive Network</li>
         <li>A network of global web servers storing identical, up-to-date, versions of<br />code and documentation for R</li>
      </ul>
      <p><br /><strong>Download and Install R:</strong></p>
      <ul>
         <li>Use the CRAN mirror nearest to you to download R setup at a faster<br />speed. Go to <a href="url"> http://cran.r-project.org</a></li>
         <li>Select one of the three download links according to your machine.</li>
      </ul>
      <img src="sdcard/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png" alt="downloadr" width="191" height="129" /> 
      <ul>
         <li>Run the R set up and follow the instructions of the installer.</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

I get the follwoing error

> chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///sdcard/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png"

Comment: `How to open a image stored locally using html code in android?` AND `so when the html loads the image doesn't load` ??? That makes no sense.

Comment: `using jsoup to parse and display html content`. You cannot use jsoup to display html content. Please rephrase.

Comment: I am so sorry @greenapps please can you check my updated question.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) to get the real path of the sdcard:

```
 Boolean isSDPresent = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
                if (isSDPresent)
                {
                    image.attr("src", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png");
                }else
                {
                    image.attr("src","/storage/emulated/0/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png");
                }
```

#### I suggest to load the image into your WebView this method:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

String imagePath = "file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png";
//Create an html template.
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
//Load the image into your WebView:
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response but I still face the same problem.This is the part of code that I changed if (isSDPresent)
                {
                    image.attr("src",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png");
                }else
                {
                    image.attr("src","/storage/emulated/0/rreadyreckoner_images/download-r.png");
                }

Comment: @anup try with the suggested method and tell about the results! :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Elenasys just change this line String html ="<html><head></head><body><img src="+ imagePath + "></body></html>"; Keep up the good work.