# How can an asset HTML file access image files in storage directory?

Tags: java, android, html

I have a webview that loads HTML files from asset folder. My app downloads certain images and stores them in the app's internal storage (/data/data/package name/downloads/images/)

I want the HTML files IMG src to reference these images in internal storage.

I tried setting it to src="/data/data/package name/downloads/images/img1.png" and it doesn't work.

What is the correct way to reference it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779789/android-development-using-image-from-assets-in-a-webviews-html

Comment: Try to pass the File.getPath() of the image as the src.